# I can't get a user access token with manage_pages permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I have a code that logs a user in and then should get a list of the user's Pages in which he is an admin of.

```
FB.login(function (r) {
    if (r.authResponse) {

        FB.api("/me/accounts", "GET", { access_token: r.authResponse.accessToken }, function (response) {
            ..//
        });

    } else {
        // not auth / cancelled the login!
    }
}, { scope: "manage_pages, publish_pages, publish_actions" });
```

The problem I think is the user access token generated does not have manage_pages permission even though I asked for it during log in. I confirmed this by getting the user access token generated after logging in and then using Facebook's Access Token Debugger. How do I get a user access token with manage pages permission?

Comment: Are you testing this with a user that has a role in the app? Otherwise, you need to get your usage of those permissions reviewed by Facebook before you can ask normal users for them.

Comment: @CBroe - So what happens if I don't get reviewed? Do you mean this will work once I get reviewed and approved? Could I test this without review?

Comment: Any user with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) can be asked for any permission, even before it is reviewed – mainly for testing purposes.